# Auto-provision new hosts with docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm, rancher

How can you automatically provision new machines when docker swarm detects there are not enough resources to schedule all services?

I use a setup with rancher and the docker swarm scheduler, and if there are not enough resources, the service creation fails:

```
exit status 1: Creating stresstest2_workerb1_1 Creating stresstest2_workerb2_1 no resources available to schedule container
```

I can poll for this status and call docker machine when  needed, but rancher will not attempt to re-schedule the missing services. I wonder if there is a more integrated solution, maybe a hook within docker swarm that can be used to dynamically call docker-machine to create or remove machines.

I'm currently deciding between Rancher with Docker 1.11 + Docker Swarm or Docker 1.12 in Swarm Mode, so a solution for any would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the new Docker Swarm Mode that came in 1.12? There isn't currently a hook in Docker Swarm for this. However with Swarm Mode, you could use the [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/#/docker-events) to collect events that trigger it instead of polling.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there doesn't seem to be an event for *failed to deploy container due to lack of resources*, or am I missing something?

Comment: I tried it out, there are no events triggered when containers can not be scheduled due to lack of resources.

Comment: It would be great to post this in the issue tracker: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues